# How can I add a parameter to my generic method?

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSpacedOptions<T>() where T : struct
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        if (!t.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum type");
        }
        var options = Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<T>()
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = ((int) Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString(),
                Text = Regex.Replace(x.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim()
            });
        return options;
    }
```

What I need to do is to add a boolean parameter called zeroPad. So that if it is not supplied the method will be unchanged but if supplied then the Text output will be always a two digit string such as "01", "04" or "77".

How can I add that parameter. There seems no place to add it.

Comment: Could you clarify a few things? 1. The method doesn't compile. The line with `((int) Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString()` tries to cast a string to an int. What is it intended to do here? 2. What sort of names do the enum values have? Can you give some example enums & outputs? 3. Where does your desired value for the two digit strings come from? From the names of the enum values somehow? 4. Are you asking about how to add a new parameter to GetSpacedOptions (as the question title suggests) or about how to modify the body of the method to do what you describe (as the body of the question suggests)?

Comment: Ah, ignore my question #1, I guessed the wrong type for SelectListItem.Value, that's why it wouldn't compile for me. I'm still curious about the other points. If the existing answers haven't covered what you wanted, please answer them and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about providing the default value as `false`.-

```
public static IEnumerable<TestClass> GetSpacedOptions<T>(bool zeroPad = false)
                                              where T : struct
```

User can call it in both ways -

```
GetSpacedOptions<MyEnum>(true);
```

If value is not specified, `zeroPad` value will be `false` by default

```
GetSpacedOptions<MyEnum>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters goes between the parentheses:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSpacedOptions<T>(bool zeroPad) where T : struct
{
  ...
}
```

Overload with the parameterless method that calls the one with the parameter:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSpacedOptions<T>() where T : struct
{
  return GetSpacedOptions<T>(false);
}
```